# Start /usr/bin/login instead of /bin/bash in PyCharm terminal

Tags: bash, shell, pycharm

After updating to PyCharm 2016.3 my terminal has changed.
In 2016.2 it fired up identical to iTerm or Terminal. Now I am supposed to run /usr/bin/login to achieve it, because PyCharm only invokes /bin/bash and if I change shell path to /usr/bin/login in preferences terminal will collapse right after starting. I assume this is happening because /usr/bin/login requires login and password.

I am a little bit confused and after some research can't figure out what is going under the hood and what should I do to startup shell as in iTerm. May somebody clarify this, please?

**UPD:** Fixed in 2016.3.2 (in my case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me in `macOS`:

1) Open in PyCharm

```
Preferences > Tools > Terminal > Shell path
```

2) Replace

```
/bin/bash
```

with

```
/bin/sh -login -i
```

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html

Comment: Not working for me. I am using PyCharm 2019.3 on Linux Mint Tricia.

Comment: @ManishGupta, my original answer was tested only in my `macOS`. 
I'll update the answer to reflect it. BTW, it still works for me in PyCharm 2019.3

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too, and it is quite annoying.

The best solution I found so far is to run `bash -l` in the Terminal of PyCharm every time I start using it.

I tried to put `/bin/bash -l` into PyCharm `Preferences > Tools > Terminal > Shell path`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and this issue is common when one installs PyCharm CE from the application market like Software Center in Ubuntu. To get /bin/bash by default in PyCharm CE terminal, you should install it by using Jetbrains Toolbox for any version of PyCharm CE and Linux distro.